# Why title tag is used in the hreflang markup?

Tags: html, hreflang

What is the practical use of Title tag in the hreflang markup?

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.mozilla.org/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="an" href="https://www.mozilla.org/an/" title="aragonés">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="az" href="https://www.mozilla.org/az/" title="Azərbaycanca">
```

Answer (score -1):

according to w3school it serves this purpose

> Defines a preferred or an alternate stylesheet

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: Sorry, that seems irrelevant. Please check the markup again. It's not about stylesheet but hreflang.

Comment: @CuriousGK [This article](https://html.com/attributes/link-title/) might help you on your way :-). Apparently, the `title` attribute is used so users can switch languages in their browser (?).

Comment: @node_modules See the duplicate target above. The title attribute on stylesheet links indicates alternate stylesheets to be loaded (for any reason the author desires, including but not limited to loading styles for different languages).

Comment: @TylerH Not sure what you're talking about, but if you read the article, you'll not only see that it is about stylesheets, but also explaining using the `hreflang` attribute.

Comment: @node_modules I'm talking about the question and the answer to it, as well as your wonderment out loud about what it is 'apparently' for. The duplicate target's answer explains authoritatively what it is for. My comment points that out and also details how that includes the reason you mentioned (different languages) but how that is not the exclusive reason for the attribute being used on that element.